# C言語からアセンブリ言語に書き出した時の計算量について

Tags: c, assembly, 計算量

### 前提と質問内容

（前提）3x3の正方行列の掛け算を行うプログラムをC言語で書き、
[compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/)というC言語のアセンブラ出力を確認できるページで
x86-64 icc 19.0.1とMIPS gcc 5.4のアセンブリ言語に出力しました。

（質問）内側のループにおける代入文とフロー制御の命令回数と、プログラム全体の計算複雑度はC言語からアセンブリ言語に変換すると変わるのでしょうか。

### 現在の見解

C言語のプログラムでは、内側のループにおける代入文とフロー制御(C言語はプログラム上でプログラマーが行う必要がないのかもしれませんが）の命令数は

```
C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
```

の１回だと考えています。

またプログラム全体の計算複雑度はO(N^3)だと思います。

（現在の見解）内側のループにおける代入文とフロー制御は、アセンブリ言語の方が明確にアドレスなどを指定しないといけないので、命令数が増えると考えています。一方、プログラム全体の計算複雑度はどのように考えればいいのかアセンブリ言語を見てもわからず困っています。

内側のループにおける代入文とフロー制御について、
例えばMIPSの場合、compiler explorerで

```
C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
```

と対応する以下の部分の命令数を数えれば「内側のループにおける代入文とフロー制御の命令回数」と言えるのでしょうか。

```
lw $3,32($fp)
nop
move $2,$3
sll $2,$2,1
addu $2,$2,$3
lw $3,36($fp)
nop
addu $2,$2,$3
sll $2,$2,3
addiu $3,$fp,32
addu $2,$3,$2
lwc1 $f2,164($2)
nop
lwc1 $f3,160($2)
lw $3,32($fp)
nop
move $2,$3
sll $2,$2,1
addu $2,$2,$3
lw $3,40($fp)
nop
addu $2,$2,$3
sll $2,$2,3
addiu $3,$fp,32
addu $2,$3,$2
lwc1 $f4,20($2)
nop
lwc1 $f5,16($2)
lw $3,40($fp)
nop
move $2,$3
sll $2,$2,1
addu $2,$2,$3
lw $3,36($fp)
nop
addu $2,$2,$3
sll $2,$2,3
addiu $3,$fp,32
addu $2,$3,$2
lwc1 $f0,92($2)
nop
lwc1 $f1,88($2)
nop
mul.d $f0,$f4,$f0
add.d $f0,$f2,$f0
lw $3,32($fp)
nop
move $2,$3
sll $2,$2,1
addu $2,$2,$3
lw $3,36($fp)
nop
addu $2,$2,$3
sll $2,$2,3
addiu $3,$fp,32
addu $2,$3,$2
swc1 $f0,164($2)
swc1 $f1,160($2)
```

### 実行中のプログラム

x86-64 icc 19.0.1とMIPS gcc 5.4のアセンブリ言語に出力したプログラムも掲載しましたが、C言語と対応する部分を確認するには、以下のC言語のプログラムを[compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/)に貼り付けて変換いただく方がわかりやすいと思います。

C言語のプログラム

```c
#include<stdio.h>

#define N 3
int 
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double A[N][N] = {
        {1.0, 3.0, 1.0},
        {3.0, 1.0, 3.0},
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0}
    };

    double B[N][N] = {
        {6.0, 1.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 1.0, 6.0},
        {0.0, 1.0, 1.0}
    };

    double C[N][N] = {
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
    };
    int i, j, k;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
            for(k=0; k<N; k++)
                C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
            printf("C[%d][%d] = %f\n", i, j, C[i][j]);
}
```

MIPSのプログラム

```
$LC2:
        .ascii  "C[%d][%d] = %f\012\000"
$LC0:
        .word   1072693248
        .word   0
        .word   1074266112
        .word   0
        .word   1072693248
        .word   0
        .word   1074266112
        .word   0
        .word   1072693248
        .word   0
        .word   1074266112
        .word   0
        .word   1072693248
        .word   0
        .word   1072693248
        .word   0
        .word   1072693248
        .word   0
$LC1:
        .word   1075314688
        .word   0
        .word   1072693248
        .word   0
        .word   0
        .word   0
        .word   0
        .word   0
        .word   1072693248
        .word   0
        .word   1075314688
        .word   0
        .word   0
        .word   0
        .word   1072693248
        .word   0
        .word   1072693248
        .word   0
main:
        addiu   $sp,$sp,-272
        sw      $31,268($sp)
        sw      $fp,264($sp)
        move    $fp,$sp
        sw      $4,272($fp)
        sw      $5,276($fp)
        lui     $2,%hi($LC0)
        addiu   $3,$fp,48
        addiu   $2,$2,%lo($LC0)
        li      $4,72                 # 0x48
        move    $6,$4
        move    $5,$2
        move    $4,$3
        jal     memcpy
        nop

        lui     $2,%hi($LC1)
        addiu   $3,$fp,120
        addiu   $2,$2,%lo($LC1)
        li      $4,72                 # 0x48
        move    $6,$4
        move    $5,$2
        move    $4,$3
        jal     memcpy
        nop

        sw      $0,196($fp)
        sw      $0,192($fp)
        sw      $0,204($fp)
        sw      $0,200($fp)
        sw      $0,212($fp)
        sw      $0,208($fp)
        sw      $0,220($fp)
        sw      $0,216($fp)
        sw      $0,228($fp)
        sw      $0,224($fp)
        sw      $0,236($fp)
        sw      $0,232($fp)
        sw      $0,244($fp)
        sw      $0,240($fp)
        sw      $0,252($fp)
        sw      $0,248($fp)
        sw      $0,260($fp)
        sw      $0,256($fp)
        sw      $0,32($fp)
$L7:
        lw      $2,32($fp)
        nop
        slt     $2,$2,3
        beq     $2,$0,$L2
        nop

        sw      $0,36($fp)
$L6:
        lw      $2,36($fp)
        nop
        slt     $2,$2,3
        beq     $2,$0,$L3
        nop

        sw      $0,40($fp)
$L5:
        lw      $2,40($fp)
        nop
        slt     $2,$2,3
        beq     $2,$0,$L4
        nop

        lw      $3,32($fp)
        nop
        move    $2,$3
        sll     $2,$2,1
        addu    $2,$2,$3
        lw      $3,36($fp)
        nop
        addu    $2,$2,$3
        sll     $2,$2,3
        addiu   $3,$fp,32
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        lwc1    $f2,164($2)
        nop
        lwc1    $f3,160($2)
        lw      $3,32($fp)
        nop
        move    $2,$3
        sll     $2,$2,1
        addu    $2,$2,$3
        lw      $3,40($fp)
        nop
        addu    $2,$2,$3
        sll     $2,$2,3
        addiu   $3,$fp,32
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        lwc1    $f4,20($2)
        nop
        lwc1    $f5,16($2)
        lw      $3,40($fp)
        nop
        move    $2,$3
        sll     $2,$2,1
        addu    $2,$2,$3
        lw      $3,36($fp)
        nop
        addu    $2,$2,$3
        sll     $2,$2,3
        addiu   $3,$fp,32
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        lwc1    $f0,92($2)
        nop
        lwc1    $f1,88($2)
        nop
        mul.d   $f0,$f4,$f0
        add.d   $f0,$f2,$f0
        lw      $3,32($fp)
        nop
        move    $2,$3
        sll     $2,$2,1
        addu    $2,$2,$3
        lw      $3,36($fp)
        nop
        addu    $2,$2,$3
        sll     $2,$2,3
        addiu   $3,$fp,32
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        swc1    $f0,164($2)
        swc1    $f1,160($2)
        lw      $2,40($fp)
        nop
        addiu   $2,$2,1
        sw      $2,40($fp)
        b       $L5
        nop

$L4:
        lw      $2,36($fp)
        nop
        addiu   $2,$2,1
        sw      $2,36($fp)
        b       $L6
        nop

$L3:
        lw      $2,32($fp)
        nop
        addiu   $2,$2,1
        sw      $2,32($fp)
        b       $L7
        nop

$L2:
        sw      $0,32($fp)
$L11:
        lw      $2,32($fp)
        nop
        slt     $2,$2,3
        beq     $2,$0,$L8
        nop

        sw      $0,36($fp)
$L10:
        lw      $2,36($fp)
        nop
        slt     $2,$2,3
        beq     $2,$0,$L9
        nop

        lw      $3,32($fp)
        nop
        move    $2,$3
        sll     $2,$2,1
        addu    $2,$2,$3
        lw      $3,36($fp)
        nop
        addu    $2,$2,$3
        sll     $2,$2,3
        addiu   $3,$fp,32
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        lwc1    $f0,164($2)
        nop
        lwc1    $f1,160($2)
        nop
        swc1    $f0,20($sp)
        swc1    $f1,16($sp)
        lw      $6,36($fp)
        lw      $5,32($fp)
        lui     $2,%hi($LC2)
        addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC2)
        jal     printf
        nop

        lw      $2,36($fp)
        nop
        addiu   $2,$2,1
        sw      $2,36($fp)
        b       $L10
        nop

$L9:
        lw      $2,32($fp)
        nop
        addiu   $2,$2,1
        sw      $2,32($fp)
        b       $L11
        nop

$L8:
        move    $2,$0
        move    $sp,$fp
        lw      $31,268($sp)
        lw      $fp,264($sp)
        addiu   $sp,$sp,272
        j       $31
        nop
```

x86-64 のプログラム

```
.L_2__STRING.0:
        .long   1680169795
        .long   1680169821
        .long   540876893
        .long   681509

main:
        push      rbp                                           #7.1
        mov       rbp, rsp                                      #7.1
        sub       rsp, 256                                      #7.1
        mov       QWORD PTR [-8+rbp], rbx                       #7.1[spill]
        mov       DWORD PTR [-240+rbp], edi                     #7.1
        mov       QWORD PTR [-232+rbp], rsi                     #7.1
        lea       rax, QWORD PTR [-224+rbp]                     #8.17
        mov       edx, offset flat: A.136.0                     #8.17
        mov       ecx, 72                                       #8.17
        mov       rdi, rax                                      #8.17
        mov       rsi, rdx                                      #8.17
        mov       eax, ecx                                      #8.17
        shr       rcx, 2                                        #8.17
        rep   movsd                                             #8.17
        mov       ecx, eax                                      #8.17
        and       ecx, 3                                        #8.17
        rep   movsb                                             #8.17
        lea       rax, QWORD PTR [-152+rbp]                     #14.17
        mov       edx, offset flat: B.136.0                     #14.17
        mov       ecx, 72                                       #14.17
        mov       rdi, rax                                      #14.17
        mov       rsi, rdx                                      #14.17
        mov       eax, ecx                                      #14.17
        shr       rcx, 2                                        #14.17
        rep   movsd                                             #14.17
        mov       ecx, eax                                      #14.17
        and       ecx, 3                                        #14.17
        rep   movsb                                             #14.17
        lea       rax, QWORD PTR [-80+rbp]                      #20.17
        mov       edx, 0                                        #20.17
        mov       ecx, 72                                       #20.17
        mov       rdi, rax                                      #20.17
        mov       eax, edx                                      #20.17
        and       eax, 65535                                    #20.17
        mov       ah, al                                        #20.17
        mov       edx, eax                                      #20.17
        shl       eax, 16                                       #20.17
        or        eax, edx                                      #20.17
        mov       esi, ecx                                      #20.17
        shr       rcx, 2                                        #20.17
        rep   stosd                                             #20.17
        mov       ecx, esi                                      #20.17
        and       ecx, 3                                        #20.17
        rep   stosb                                             #20.17
        mov       DWORD PTR [-256+rbp], 0                       #27.6
..B1.5:                         # Preds ..B1.6 ..B1.4
        mov       eax, DWORD PTR [-256+rbp]                     #27.11
        cmp       eax, 3                                        #27.13
        jl        ..B1.7        # Prob 50%                      #27.13
        jmp       ..B1.13       # Prob 100%                     #27.13
..B1.6:                         # Preds ..B1.8
        mov       eax, 1                                        #27.16
        add       eax, DWORD PTR [-256+rbp]                     #27.16
        mov       DWORD PTR [-256+rbp], eax                     #27.16
        jmp       ..B1.5        # Prob 100%                     #27.16
..B1.7:                         # Preds ..B1.5
        mov       DWORD PTR [-252+rbp], 0                       #28.7
..B1.8:                         # Preds ..B1.9 ..B1.7
        mov       eax, DWORD PTR [-252+rbp]                     #28.12
        cmp       eax, 3                                        #28.14
        jl        ..B1.10       # Prob 50%                      #28.14
        jmp       ..B1.6        # Prob 100%                     #28.14
..B1.9:                         # Preds ..B1.11
        mov       eax, 1                                        #28.17
        add       eax, DWORD PTR [-252+rbp]                     #28.17
        mov       DWORD PTR [-252+rbp], eax                     #28.17
        jmp       ..B1.8        # Prob 100%                     #28.17
..B1.10:                        # Preds ..B1.8
        mov       DWORD PTR [-248+rbp], 0                       #29.8
..B1.11:                        # Preds ..B1.12 ..B1.10
        mov       eax, DWORD PTR [-248+rbp]                     #29.13
        cmp       eax, 3                                        #29.15
        jge       ..B1.9        # Prob 50%                      #29.15
        lea       rax, QWORD PTR [-80+rbp]                      #30.5
        mov       edx, DWORD PTR [-256+rbp]                     #30.7
        movsxd    rdx, edx                                      #30.5
        imul      rdx, rdx, 24                                  #30.5
        add       rax, rdx                                      #30.5
        mov       edx, DWORD PTR [-252+rbp]                     #30.10
        movsxd    rdx, edx                                      #30.5
        imul      rdx, rdx, 8                                   #30.5
        add       rax, rdx                                      #30.5
        lea       rdx, QWORD PTR [-224+rbp]                     #30.16
        mov       ecx, DWORD PTR [-256+rbp]                     #30.18
        movsxd    rcx, ecx                                      #30.16
        imul      rcx, rcx, 24                                  #30.16
        add       rdx, rcx                                      #30.16
        mov       ecx, DWORD PTR [-248+rbp]                     #30.21
        movsxd    rcx, ecx                                      #30.16
        imul      rcx, rcx, 8                                   #30.16
        add       rdx, rcx                                      #30.16
        movsd     xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx]                         #30.16
        lea       rdx, QWORD PTR [-152+rbp]                     #30.24
        mov       ecx, DWORD PTR [-248+rbp]                     #30.26
        movsxd    rcx, ecx                                      #30.24
        imul      rcx, rcx, 24                                  #30.24
        add       rdx, rcx                                      #30.24
        mov       ecx, DWORD PTR [-252+rbp]                     #30.29
        movsxd    rcx, ecx                                      #30.24
        imul      rcx, rcx, 8                                   #30.24
        add       rdx, rcx                                      #30.24
        movsd     xmm1, QWORD PTR [rdx]                         #30.24
        mulsd     xmm0, xmm1                                    #30.24
        movsd     xmm1, QWORD PTR [rax]                         #30.5
        addsd     xmm1, xmm0                                    #30.5
        lea       rax, QWORD PTR [-80+rbp]                      #30.5
        mov       edx, DWORD PTR [-256+rbp]                     #30.7
        movsxd    rdx, edx                                      #30.5
        imul      rdx, rdx, 24                                  #30.5
        add       rax, rdx                                      #30.5
        mov       edx, DWORD PTR [-252+rbp]                     #30.10
        movsxd    rdx, edx                                      #30.5
        imul      rdx, rdx, 8                                   #30.5
        add       rax, rdx                                      #30.5
        movsd     QWORD PTR [rax], xmm1                         #30.5
        mov       eax, 1                                        #29.18
        add       eax, DWORD PTR [-248+rbp]                     #29.18
        mov       DWORD PTR [-248+rbp], eax                     #29.18
        jmp       ..B1.11       # Prob 100%                     #29.18
..B1.13:                        # Preds ..B1.5
        mov       DWORD PTR [-256+rbp], 0                       #32.6
..B1.14:                        # Preds ..B1.15 ..B1.13
        mov       eax, DWORD PTR [-256+rbp]                     #32.11
        cmp       eax, 3                                        #32.13
        jl        ..B1.16       # Prob 50%                      #32.13
        jmp       ..B1.20       # Prob 100%                     #32.13
..B1.15:                        # Preds ..B1.17
        mov       eax, 1                                        #32.16
        add       eax, DWORD PTR [-256+rbp]                     #32.16
        mov       DWORD PTR [-256+rbp], eax                     #32.16
        jmp       ..B1.14       # Prob 100%                     #32.16
..B1.16:                        # Preds ..B1.14
        mov       DWORD PTR [-252+rbp], 0                       #33.7
..B1.17:                        # Preds ..B1.18 ..B1.16
        mov       eax, DWORD PTR [-252+rbp]                     #33.12
        cmp       eax, 3                                        #33.14
        jl        ..B1.19       # Prob 50%                      #33.14
        jmp       ..B1.15       # Prob 100%                     #33.14
..B1.18:                        # Preds ..B1.23
        mov       eax, 1                                        #33.17
        add       eax, DWORD PTR [-252+rbp]                     #33.17
        mov       DWORD PTR [-252+rbp], eax                     #33.17
        jmp       ..B1.17       # Prob 100%                     #33.17
..B1.19:                        # Preds ..B1.17
        mov       eax, offset flat: .L_2__STRING.0              #34.4
        mov       edx, DWORD PTR [-256+rbp]                     #34.4
        mov       ecx, DWORD PTR [-252+rbp]                     #34.4
        lea       rbx, QWORD PTR [-80+rbp]                      #34.4
        mov       esi, DWORD PTR [-256+rbp]                     #34.4
        movsxd    rsi, esi                                      #34.4
        imul      rsi, rsi, 24                                  #34.4
        add       rbx, rsi                                      #34.4
        mov       esi, DWORD PTR [-252+rbp]                     #34.4
        movsxd    rsi, esi                                      #34.4
        imul      rsi, rsi, 8                                   #34.4
        add       rbx, rsi                                      #34.4
        movsd     xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbx]                         #34.4
        mov       rdi, rax                                      #34.4
        mov       esi, edx                                      #34.4
        mov       edx, ecx                                      #34.4
        mov       eax, 1                                        #34.4
        call      printf                                        #34.4
        mov       DWORD PTR [-244+rbp], eax                     #34.4
        jmp       ..B1.18       # Prob 100%                     #34.4
..B1.20:                        # Preds ..B1.14
        mov       eax, 0                                        #35.1
        mov       rbx, QWORD PTR [-8+rbp]                       #35.1[spill]
        leave                                                   #35.1
        ret                                                     #35.1
A.136.0:
        .long   0x00000000,0x3ff00000
        .long   0x00000000,0x40080000
        .long   0x00000000,0x3ff00000
        .long   0x00000000,0x40080000
        .long   0x00000000,0x3ff00000
        .long   0x00000000,0x40080000
        .long   0x00000000,0x3ff00000
        .long   0x00000000,0x3ff00000
        .long   0x00000000,0x3ff00000
B.136.0:
        .long   0x00000000,0x40180000
        .long   0x00000000,0x3ff00000
        .long   0x00000000,0x00000000
        .long   0x00000000,0x00000000
        .long   0x00000000,0x3ff00000
        .long   0x00000000,0x40180000
        .long   0x00000000,0x00000000
        .long   0x00000000,0x3ff00000
        .long   0x00000000,0x3ff00000
        .long   0x00000000,0x00000000
        .long   0x00000000,0x00000000
        .long   0x00000000,0x00000000
        .long   0x00000000,0x00000000
        .long   0x00000000,0x00000000
        .long   0x00000000,0x00000000
        .long   0x00000000,0x00000000
        .long   0x00000000,0x00000000
        .long   0x00000000,0x00000000
```

Comment: 私には、回答する能力はありませんが、質問の意図がはっきりすれば、回答できる人がいるかもしれません。Cコンパイラは、最適化の度合いによって、生成されるアセンブラ（機械語）のコードは変わってきます。

Comment: 質問で言っている「命令回数」と言うのは「命令がコードやバイナリに現れる回数(言わば命令の個数)」ですか？それもと「実際に実行されたときに命令が実行される回数」ですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> （質問）内側のループにおける代入文とフロー制御の命令回数と、プログラム全体の計算複雑度はC言語からアセンブリ言語に変換すると変わるのでしょうか。

一般論として、あるアルゴリズムの実装言語を機械変換（例: C言語→アセンブリ言語へのコンパイル）しても、ビッグ・オー記法の計算複雑度は変化しません。

というよりも「計算複雑度」はアルゴリズムそれ自身から決まりますから、具体的な実装プログラミング言語には依存しないと解釈すべきです。

> またプログラム全体の計算複雑度はO(N^3)だと思います。

“C言語やアセンブリ言語で記述されたプログラム”の計算複雑度という表現がすでに不正確であり、
“今はたまたまC言語やアセンブリ言語で記述している行列乗算アルゴリズム”の計算複雑度を議論すべきです。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。プログラム全体の計算複雑度に関しては、“今はたまたまC言語やアセンブリ言語で記述している行列乗算アルゴリズム”であり、O(N^3)ということは理解できました。一方で、内側のループにおける代入文とフロー制御の命令回数もC言語やアセンブリ言語で、同じとは考えにくいのですが（コードの行数が大きく違うため）、そちらについての見解もお聞かせ願えると幸いです。

Comment: アセンブリ言語の命令の行数を問題視されているようですが、C言語の一行はアセンブリ言語で一行に変換できるようなものではありません。C言語で書くと一行でも実際にはかなりのCPU命令を使っているのが普通です。また、大雑把な説明ですが、アセンブリ言語では無駄に行数が多く見えても、命令の総クロック数が少ない方が早いプログラムになります。

Comment: @NPP 後半について、あなたが何を疑問視しているのかを全く理解できておらず私には何も回答しようがありません。少なくとも、C言語プログラムの命令回数（＝論理行数のこと？）とアセンブリ言語の命令数（機械語ニーモニック数のこと？）を直接比較することに何の意味も見いだせません。C言語とアセンブリ言語とでは、プログラミング言語の抽象化能力が全く異なります。アセンブリ言語は機械語に近い（もしくは1:1の）低レイヤを扱うため、命令の数＝プログラム行数だけで評価すれば肥大化して当然です。

Comment: @SugiyamaKoichi コメントありがとうございます。「アセンブリ言語では無駄に行数が多く見えても、命令の総クロック数が少ない方が早いプログラムになります」という話に関しまして計算複雑度（オーダー）は目視ですが、アセンブリ言語では総クロック数はどのように計算すればいいのでしょうか

Comment: 普通はアセンブリ言語のリファレンスにニーモニックごとの消費サイクルが記載されていると思いますので、それらを元に積算することになります。ツール等で計測できるものもあるかもしれませんが、ちょっとそこのところは今ほとんど触っていないのではっきりしたことは判りません。

Comment: MIPSでもx86でも、最近のまともなプロセッサでは「アセンブリ言語での総クロック数」の事前計算は事実上不可能です。CPUレジスタ間の単純演算であればまだ予測可能かもしれませんが、メモリロード/ストア命令ではCPUキャッシュ状態によって所要クロック数が大きく変動します。現実的には、プロファイラ等を用いてアセンブリ言語プログラムの所要時間を計測することになるでしょうね。